# Angular 4 populate table with a json

Tags: php, json, angular

Below is my working Code!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProdukteService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getProdukte() {
        return this.http.get('assets/demo/data/produkte.json')
               .toPromise()
               .then(res => <any[]> res.json().records)
               .then(records => { return records; });
    }
}
```

With that Code + HTML I can populate my table and its working!:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="produkte" [style]="{'margin-bottom':'20px'}">
    <p-header>Recent Sales</p-header>
    <p-column field="Produktitel" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="Preis" header="Year"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

But now I want/need the JSON from a database like that:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProdukteService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getProdukte() {
        return this.http.get('http://cube-developing.de/connect.php')
               .toPromise()
               .then(res => <any[]> res.json().records)
               .then(records => { return records; });
    }
}
```

But thats not working... What do I have to change to get this working?
JSON is valid!

Comment: Try getProdukte() {return this.http.get('http://cube-developing.de/connect.php').map(res => <any[]> res.json().records);}

Comment: does not work too :/

Comment: Your response is still not valid, or as I should say it **is** valid as it comes initially with slashes, but when you parse it, it becomes invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve a Promise in the component `constructor` or `onInit` provided the API is properly returning data.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ProdukteService
      .getProdukte()
      .then(result => {console.log(result); this.data = result)}) // assign data to variable
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

you can acheive the same using **Observables**.

**Service**

```
getProdukte() {
        return this.http.get('http://cube-developing.de/connect.php')
                .map(res => res.json().records)
         }
```

**In Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.ProdukteService
          .getProdukte()
          .subscribe(result => {console.log(result); this.data = result)}); // assign data to variable

    }
```

Comment: undefined
main.bundle.js (1036,44)

Comment: sry im kinda new in angular, im getting 2 undefined in both component

Comment: Try and go from service what is the data you are getting.

Comment: all i get in the console is "undefined"

Comment: at which level component or service

Comment: in both, seems like my json isnt valid or why isnt he getting informations mhm